# R deep learning, multiple outputs

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

Is it possible to create a deep learning net that gives multiple outputs?
The reason for doing this is to also try to capture the relationships between outputs. 
In the examples given I can only create one output.

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
irisPath = system.file("extdata", "iris.csv", package = "h2o")
iris.hex = h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = irisPath)
h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5, data = iris.hex, activation = "Tanh", 
             hidden = c(10, 10), epochs = 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like multiple response columns are currently supported in H2O ([H2O FAQ](http://0xdata.com/product/faq/#H2OMultiOutput) and [H2O Google Group topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/gMKGiwowOPw)). Their suggestion is to train a new model for each response.

(Nonsensical) example:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O <- h2o.init()
irisPath <- system.file("extdata", "iris.csv", package = "h2o")
iris.hex <- h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = irisPath)

m1 <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:2, y = 3, data = iris.hex, activation = "Tanh", 
         hidden = c(10, 10), epochs = 5, classification = FALSE)
m2 <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:2, y = 4, data = iris.hex, activation = "Tanh", 
         hidden = c(10, 10), epochs = 5, classification = FALSE)
```

However, it appears that multiple responses are available through the [deepnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepnet/index.html) package (check `library(sos); findFn("deep learning")`).

```
library(deepnet)
x <- as.matrix(iris[,1:2])
y <- as.matrix(iris[,3:4])
m3 <- dbn.dnn.train(x = x, y = y, hidden = c(5,5))
```